# PowerShell: How to suppress cmdlet confirmation when the common parameter isn't supported

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm working on a small script to test ARM templates for Azure in PowerShell. It uses the `Test-AzResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet. It tests if an ARM template is valid. I'd like to suppress prompts for this cmdlet. I want my script to return with a positive/negative response if the template is valid. However, after viewing info about the cmdlet through `Get-Help`, it doesn't look like it supports the `Confirm` common parameter. So I'm forced to 'continue' 2-3 times during script execution instead of getting an immediate result.

[image]

So my question is, do I have any options to get around this for a cmdlet such as this? Or since it doesn't support the `Confirm` common parameter, am I just out of luck and forced to deal with "Continue with this operation?" prompts?

Comment: @Birdman I'm not actually getting any prompts when doing a quick test on an sample template. Could you provide some code examples of what you are running this is causing prompts to show up? (I tested on PS6 and PS5.1. I'm using 1.2.1 of Az.Resources module.)

Comment: @ShawnMelton I think it's because of the -debug flag I added as a common parameter. The cmdlet doesn't return anything unless an error occurs, so I added the debug flag so I could view what was going on since it doesn't return any kind of object on success. After removing the debug flag, it appears to be working without any prompts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `-debug` common parameter to the cmdlet which appears to have created the prompts which are occurring. I replaced it with `-verbose` when doing some testing just so there wasn't so much feedback on the console. It was then I realized the prompts disappeared. So the problem appears to have been the debugging common parameter.

If anyone has more info on this feel free to comment. (i.e. does the debug common parameter always spawn confirm prompts, etc.)